# Getting diff. num of features in train and test data after passing through the same pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, pipeline, kaggle

I am working on the introductory **Titanic** problem in ***Kaggle***.
Here I wanted to design a *pipeline* to pre-process data.
I have written the following code for it:

```
dropColumns = ['PassengerId','Name','Ticket','Cabin']
numColumns = ['Age','SibSp','Parch','Fare']
catColumns = ['Sex','Embarked']
```

Num Pipeline:

```
num_pipeline = Pipeline([
('imputer',SimpleImputer(strategy="median")),
('std_scaler',StandardScaler()),])
```

Full Pipeline:

```
DataPreperationPipeline = ColumnTransformer([
("num",num_pipeline,numColumns),
("cat",OneHotEncoder(),catColumns),])
```

When I do:

```
predictions = model.predict(test_prepared)
```

Error I am getting:
**X has 9 features, but model is expecting 10 features as input.**

**PS:** *This is the case with every model I am training. Even though before transformation test and train data has the same features.*

**Please tell me what to do?**

Answer (score 0):

*Apologies Guys*,

I am answering my own question here.

I made a mistake and sharing it here because I think I learned something very important.

The reason that I was getting this error was because a category column `'Embarked'` also had null values in it, which were not present in the test_data set. So when I passed it to `OneHotEncoder()` in my `full_pipeline`. It created four columns of 0 and 1 to distinguish between the four values ( 3 original values, 1 null), which my model thought to contain an extra feature.

As soon as I removed the null rows everything went well.

**Learning:**

Always remove nulls values from your categorical columns before passing them to encoders.